# AngularJS general solution to exit infinite loops on errors

Tags: angularjs, infinite-loop

It is known that AngularJS often goes into infinite loops due to several kinds of errors. I've been looking for a general solution to give an safe exit condition, but I just find specific fixes to causing bug.

Is there a way to prevent Angular looping to infinite, in special due to missing  resources, such as template, controllers, providers...?

I'm not interested in prevent errors *per se*, just don't getting browser tab crashes when they happen.

Comment: Got any solution for his?

Comment: Sadly, no......